# Adding a vector as a row to a matrix iteratively in R - using for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I created a function called AutoCorr() that will take in an ID, and produces a vector containing some statistics of interests. I would then like to add each vector as a row to a matrix "output_cisb" (43 x 16).

Here is what AutoCorr() prodces:

```
> AutoCorr("1182")
 [1] "1182"                 "4.04251700680272"     "0.245592563077202"    "4.01360544217687"    
 [5] "0.394458659738509"    "1.92857142857143"     "0.258863495453396"    "0.00549450549450549" 
 [9] "0.0402062637741741"   "-0.0299525504151839"  "-0.0760215053763439"  "-0.00118963486454654"
[13] "-0.0160279139947191"  "0.46824093004317"     "0.300800729491312"    "-0.429796668526319"
```

I could do the following but it would be very inefficient:

```
output_cisb[1,] <- AutoCorr("1001")
output_cisb[2,] <- AutoCorr("1002")
output_cisb[3,] <- AutoCorr("1041")
output_cisb[4,] <- AutoCorr("1042")
output_cisb[5,] <- AutoCorr("1052")
```

Here is my attempt to use a for loop but I couldn't seem to get it right. I would appreciate any help with this!

For loop code:

```
ID_cisb<-file_path_sans_ext(basename(filenames_cisb)) # this creates a vector containing all the IDs that I hope to pass through the Autocorr() function.   

for (i in nrow(output_cisb)){
  for (j in ID_cisb){
  output_cisb[i,] <- AutoCorr(j)
}
}
```

**UPDATES 08/27/2022:**
I tried the following code and it worked!

```
ID_cisb<-file_path_sans_ext(basename(filenames_cisb))  

for (i in seq_along(ID_cisb)){  # iterate over the index 
  # print (i)
  output_cisb[i,] <- AutoCorr(ID_cisb[i])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
output_cisb <- data.frame()
for (i in ID_cisb) {
  output_cisb <- rbind(output_cisb, AutoCorr(i))
}
```

Comment: This code makes sense to me but when I tried it, it is throwing an error telling me "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist." - could be an issue with how I programed AutoCorr() though, but thanks for the input anyway!